# Issue with webpack and npm package installation in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, npm-install, node-modules

I was suddenly having an issue in my project like this.
It was repeated and crashed my chrome:

[image]

So, I downgraded some of my packages and I downgraded my npm to 6.6.0 which was stable for my project. The main problem started after that. I removed the node_modules folder and when I tried to 
`sudo npm install` [because `npm install` says permission issue] 
it started showing these errors:

> npm info it worked if it ends with ok npm verb cli [ '/usr/bin/node',
>   npm verb cli   '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/npm', npm verb cli
>   'i', npm verb cli   '-g', npm verb cli   'npm', npm verb cli
>   '--verbose' ] npm info using npm@6.6.0 npm info using node@v10.15.0 npm
>   verb npm-session 3b7ba2a77f7e848c Unhandled rejection Error: EACCES:
>   permission denied, link '/home/.npm/_cacache/tmp/6a547224' ->
>   '/home/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/d8/e0/f8cb9554c1f6f974b32fe943e4df8353fca3cb4843dbeda6fe0d88d14eb91bec5d23ddde1751af76721044d662b479ec4c9df9f0bfcce592bbc9fc2b6f72'
>       at Error (native)
>
> npm ERR! cb() never called!
>
> npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error
>   at: npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /home/.npm/_logs/2017-06-28T00_20_47_543Z-debug.log

I have also tried `npm cache clear -f`
and also tried to install `npm install --no-cache`
But it was having problem with npm install and somehow I was getting the previous build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue by changing the permission level of my user. This was an issue because in ubuntu the node_modules folder had by default root folder permission. I have checked this by this command:
in my project folder: `ls -la`
So I got a whole list where I have seen the permission for node_modules was like this:

> drwxrwsrwx 906 root www-data    36864 মে    14 16:17 node_modules
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 my_username www-data   2407 মে    14 16:14 package.json

But my user didn't have the permission to write.
So what I did is:

`sudo chown -R my_username:my_username node_modules/`

It solved my problem.